# Aggregate multiple column result into one column by taking the first non-empty value

Tags: kql

I have a query like so:

```
Events 
| where EventType == 'test' | take 1000 | project DeviceId | distinct DeviceId 
| join kind=inner (Events | where EventType == 'test2' | take 1000 | project DeviceId | distinct DeviceId) on DeviceId
| join kind=inner (Events | where EventType == 'test3' | take 1000 | project DeviceId | distinct DeviceId) on DeviceId
| project-rename DeviceId0 = DeviceId
```

Which will return the following result:

[image]

There may be multiple columns, and based on the join type (inner/outer) the column may or may not have value

My question is does Kusto provide a way for me to aggregate the result into just 1 column DeviceId, where it contains the first non-empty value.
For example, if I have 3 columns DeviceId0, DeviceId1, DeviceId2 where the values is:

- (d1, d1, d1) => return d1
- (d1, null, null) => return d1

The column will not have different value, and at least one of them will have value (because of the join on DeviceId column)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`coalesce()` does exactly what you want (see [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/coalescefunction)).

So in your case, you should use:

```
| project coalesce(DeviceId1, DeviceId2, DeviceId3)
```